# Как получить из Firebase количество дочерних элементов базы (child) данных?

Tags: android

Есть база данных Firebase, как из нее получить количество дочерних элементов books?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак. Точнее для этого можно использовать CloudFunctions - это какие-то скрипты на nodeJs исполняющиеся на стороне серверов Гугла. Короче простого решения нет и не будет, у них это года 4 назад просили, но они не делают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте   `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`

```
mPostDatabase.child("books").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        tvWoowCount.setText(""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
    }
});
```

Тут есть аналогичный пример:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256847/get-firebase-children-count